# C# Reading data in html tags

Tags: c#

How do I read data in-between html tag such as `<strong>`. For example.

```
<strong id="food">40</strong>
```

How do I retrieve the integer 40 from there ? I tried

`myBrowser.Document.GetElementById("food").GetAttribute("value");`

Comment: Maybe 40 is food's firstChild?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-html-in-c

This is what I use in my apps.

Comment: Are you sure this is C#?  Looks more like javascript.

Comment: @Paddy: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.aspx

Comment: @SLaks - ah.  Well there you go. Didn't know about that.

Comment: Now, first of all I'm impressed how fast I got a response(thought it'd be a day at least). Second, thank you all for the good answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the `InnerHtml` property.

Comment: Now, first of all I'm impressed how fast I got a response(thought it'd be a day at least). Second, thank you all for the good answers!

Answer (score 1):

InnerText

```
[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    WebBrowser w = new WebBrowser();
    w.Navigate(String.Empty);
    HtmlDocument doc = w.Document;
    doc.Write("<html><head></head><body><p id=\"food\">40</p></body></html>");
    Console.WriteLine(doc.GetElementById("food").InnerText);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for InnerText.

Comment: Or InnerHTML will do the trick, here, as SLaks posted just before me.